# Headers when handling response to async request

Tags: c++, http, asynchronous, cpp-netlib

I'm using cpp-netlib library to create HTTP GET requests, the documentation shows [this function call](http://cpp-netlib.org/0.11.1/reference/http_client.html#http-methods):

`response_ = client_.get(request_, callback)`

where the signature of `callback` should be

`void(iterator_range<char const *> const &, boost::system::error_code const&)`

which allows me to handle the content of the response in chunks. However, this doesn't allow me to get the header information when the callback is executed (which will be in `response_`, for now I'm interested in the status code). Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Unfortunately this is one of those things that is not supported yet.

Comment: I believe you're the authoritative source on this one. Could you please make this an answer?

Comment: @DeanMichael I see you're still working on this project. Any updates on this? Then an answer can be posted.